# Change text color in echo statement with variable

Tags: php

The text that gives me the echo statement and white color, how do i give a blue color to the text, for example

```
<?php
$testo = file_get_contents('testi.txt');
echo $testo;
?>
```

The txt file is composed of many links such as this example

```
<a href='https://www.example.com/playlist/film1.mp4' target='blank'>Example text1</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `php` here, use `css`:

```
a:link { color:#0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a:visited { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
a:hover { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
a:active { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
```

---

**Update** based on OP's comment:

There are [several ways to add `css` to your file](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import), for simplicity purposes, here's an example:

```
<?php
$links = file_get_contents("links_from_text_add_css.txt");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link { color:#0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
        a:visited { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
        a:hover { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:underline; font-weight:normal; }
        a:active { color: #0000FF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?=$links?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can i apply css to print colored links to video

Comment: @Miguel I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use belowcode hope it will help you

```
 <?php
    $testo = file_get_contents('testi.txt');
    echo "<p style=\"color:#000\">".$testo."</p>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$var = "test";

echo "<p style='color:#AFA;'>" . $var . "</>";
```

There you go

Comment: There's multiple syntax-errors there, though.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying atention :)

Comment: There's still one! Besides, `$test` !== `$var`

Comment: This small details, done :)

Comment: Like I said, still one. Look at the highlighting, `"<p style="style='color:#AFA;'>"` is a direct syntax error.

Comment: You guys are putting more effort in this answer than getl0st have xD